# Rendering "partial" pages in ASP.Net? (without the <html> and such)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make use of jQueryUI AJAX tabs in my ASP.Net Webforms project.

I have come up against a wall though. For AJAX, you must render only a partial page(no `<html>` and such elements) by an external URL. How would you best do this in ASP.Net? aspx files require things like a `<html>` and `<head>` tag so those wouldn't work so the only thing that comes to mind is using cumbersome ashx files. Am I just over thinking this? Is there an easier way?

Edit:
So apparently `<html>` and such tags are not actually required. So what differences are there to rendering without the full page headers? Will some controls not work? Why wouldn't they?

Comment: To answer your last query: Most server controls that use ViewState to track their state require being placed within a form with runat="server" on it.

Comment: @Dan, many of our pages(including these AJAX ones) will have viewstate disabled, so are there any other ramifications?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Even if ViewState is disabled, many controls will simply throw an exception unless placed within a form that has runat="server" on it. Try placing a Texbox or GridView control on a page without a form and see what happens. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform.aspx

Comment: @Dan, ah thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason your .aspx pages have to have `<html>` tags.

Just go ahead and build .aspx pages with the content you want on them and point your jQuery UI tabs to each URL and it will wire up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net does not require any particular HTML tags.
You can make a partial page as an ASPX that includes whatever you want.  (Although some server-side controls might not work)

In fact, you can even make an ASPX page that renders aribtrary (non-XML) plain text.